# To Do v.s. To Doing

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Sentence in question: (From [Yahoo News](https://www.yahoo.com/news/better-ties-u-may-one-193719820.html))

> Beijing’s apparent openness to **easing** tensions with Washington may be
> no coincidence. ('to'- preposition? )

What is the difference between the above sentence and this one:

> Beijing’s apparent openness to **ease** tensions with Washington may
> be no coincidence. ('to' - the infinitive "to do"? expressing intention?)

Does the word before "to" matter? If I change "openness" to "intention", does it make a difference now?

> Beijing’s apparent **intention** to **easing** / **ease** tensions with
> Washington may be no coincidence.

Comment: Your second version is syntactically invalid. When the noun ***openness*** is modified by a prepositional phrase *(**...to X**)*, X must be a noun, not a verb (I approve of his ***openness to criticism***. And the gerund ***easing*** is a noun, for this purpose. But in *His **intention to** X*, X must be an infinitive verb (I approve of his ***intention to do something***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two completely different words here, both spelled "to".

The one in your first sentence is a *preposition*. It's followed by a noun, in this case the *gerund*, "easing". We know it's a preposition because after the adjective "open", if we want to indicate what the openness is about, we use the preposition "to".

The second sentence is incorrect, so we cannot say which "to" that is.

In your third sentence, we have the other meaning of "to", which is "infinitive-to". This "to" indicates that the following verb is in the *infinitive*. After the noun "intention", if we want to indicate what action the intention is, we use *[ "to" + base form ]*, in this case, "ease" is the correct base form verb.

To tell which "to" is being used, you have to know which "to" *correlates* with which words or with which parts of speech.

Comment: So it all depends on the word before `to`? But both `openness` and `intention` are nouns. So it is really difficult to decide which verb from to use. Are there any rules to follow?

Comment: So if the word before `to` derives from an adjective, then use `to doing`, otherwise, use `to do`?

Comment: @J.Joe The rule is word-by-word. The adjective "open" (and so too the noun "openness") collocates with the preposition "to". The noun "intention" optionally takes a "to" + infinitive verb phrase.